# Does 'thresholder' really exist?

Tags: vocabulary

I heard this word many times when listening BBC Radio 5 then I looked up dicitonaries, but it's not included in Cambridge, Oxford Learner's, Meriam Webster Dictionary and 'lexico.com'

That doesn't make sense either when I consider it as 'the one who thresholds' since 'threshold' is a noun

Comment: I've never heard it, but please add one or two examples / quotations so that we can answer you properly.

Comment: I have not heard this word used either, but new derived words are coined quite freely these days. I agree that several examples would help answer this better.

Comment: @PeterJennings the next time I hear the word, I can write down a sentence and edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a "define:thresholder" search and the only actual match (most were to "threshold") is to a medical dictionary subdomain of thefreedictionary.com, where it is defined as "A popular term for a young person on the threshold of adulthood, especially one who is anxious or depressed". I certainly would not have guessed that meaning (at least without context). Nor would I have expected it to be called "popular:. Though maybe that's simply because it's a BREism, which given the BBC source would make some sense.

Comment: Well, I'm a BrE speaker, and I've never heard of it.

Comment: I agree, "popular" is stretching it a bit far. I'm a native BrE speaker and I listen to / watch the BBC and I've never heard it or seen it in print anywhere.